# Adjusting "animateTo" location

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have a point of interest being displayed on my `mapview`, when it's clicked on, I fire an `animateTo` to center it on the screen. However, the annotation that I have popping up after it's clicked on, is sometimes too tall and gets cut off the top of the screen. I want to move the `mapview` slightly further down so the entire view will be displayed to the user without them having to move further down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the Latitude value per pixel at the center of the screen at current zoom level:

```
pixelValueY = projection.fromPixels(mapView.getwidth()/2 ,mapView.getHeight()/2).getLatitudeE6() -  projection.fromPixels(mapView.getwidth()/2 ,mapView.getHeight()/2 +1).getLatitudeE6();
```

Now suppose that you want to move map 20 pixels dowm, you just add the above value to the latitude of original center position:

```
mapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint(originalCenterLat + 20 * pixelValueY , originalCenterLon));
```

good luck